# What do we consider the defect severity in the case: "Edit window is not opening"

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, defect-tracking, bug-severity

I have a requirement which say: The user should be able to view the employee information. The user can edit/Add or delete information.I followed the following scenario:

1. I Clicked on an employee name to open its info window.
2. In the opened window I clicked on Edit--> The edit window opens
3. I Closed the Edit window and tried to open it again--> The window is not opened at all, and to open it I have to restart the application.

> What is the defect severity in this case? Critical or Major?

Note that the definition of critical and Major defects in my organization is described below:

**Critical:** Any defect causing a crash of the system/component where no workaround is available. User is not able to get the expected result
**Major:** Same as critical but complex workaround is available.

Comment: Depends on how your organization defines "complex workaround"

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it depends on how you would define "workaround" and the fact that whether your editing is saved after you close your edit window.

Consider this following scenario:

1. An employee name is clicked and its info window opens up
2. In this opened window, its Edit is clicked and its Edit window opens up
3. You edit this employee's info and close it; you click Edit again, nothing happens.

If this employee's info has been edited but not saved, then it is definitely a critical issue as there is no workaround to achieve Edit & Save; if this employee's info has been saved then it is a major inconvenience as you can potentially work around by restarting this application, hence a workaround is possible.

In short, can you please confirm whether your editing is saved?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but what is the definition of workaround from your point of view? Example: If a tool1 (related to requirment1) is not working and we have another tool2 (related to requirment2) gives the same result as tool1, so can we consider using tool2 as a valid workaround to get the desired result?

Comment: @user3584259, a workaround is a different way to achieve the same result, normally it is not considered the best option. Regarding your tool1 and tool2 example, workaround is regarding the same tool as the general rule, but without detailed context, I can not say your statement (tool1 and tool2) is wrong.

Comment: Zhang3, what do you mean by "regarding the same tool as the general rule" ?

Comment: @user3584259, say, you have a software that does something thing, then out of sudden, it does not work as expected, but you discover that there is another way to do the same thing without involving any additional software. That is what I meant by regarding the same tool

Comment: As if you mean by workaround is to get the expected result from the tool containing the defect, with the help of another tool. Example: Using the output of tool1 as input to tool2 (which contains the defect) in order to get the expected result. Am I right?

Comment: @user3584259, without the help of another tool;

Answer (score 1):

According to your explanation ,The defect severity will be (**Major**).

Critical: This defect indicates complete shut-down of the process, nothing can proceed further
Major: It is a highly severe defect and collapse the system. However, certain parts of the system remain functional

[Severity Definition](https://www.guru99.com/defect-severity-in-software-testing.html)

Comment: but there is a condition for the defect to be major which is the existence of a complex workaround, in my scenario, there is no workaround at all. So can't we consider it as critical?

Comment: if you opened edit window and functionality is working like editing ,save employee information and you can continue the testing the defect will be major. if you opened the edit window and the functionality doesn't work or the edit window can't be opened by anyway , the defect in this case will be critical.The workaround for your case that the edit window open and you can continue testing for the page, if no way to open edit window then it will be critical.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, I need your suggestion about the severity of the following issue; A search tool is supposed to display Name, Address, Salary, Position of an employee, however Position is not displayed in the result. What do we consider the severity of such defect?. I have mentioned above the descrioption of severities, For minor severity; the defect is minor when it causes the system to display incomplete result where a simple work around is available. In my scenario, the result is not complete, but I dont have a workaround to get the complete result so what is the severity in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I would say Critical
Having to shut down and restart the system is not an acceptable workaround given the stated requirements (whether or not the data was saved).